# Re-render react application from another react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react applications, i.e. `appA` and `appB`(Both have thier own `ReactDOM.render()` method) and they generate different build files i.e. `bundleA.js` and `bundleB.js` respectively. These bundles are loaded in a third application i.e. `container`(a plain js app).

There are some common states shared between them using global/window variables. For instance,

```js
window.pets = [
   {name: 'dog'},
   {name: 'cat'}
]
```

Let's say `appA` add/remove a pet to/from `window.pets`. It's updated in `appA` but not in `appB`. I tried using `useEffect` in both applications, as follow:

```js
//object dependecy dependency
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(window.pets);
},[window.pets])

//Also tried stringyting object
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(window.pets);
},[JSON.stringify(window.pets)])
```

But it's not capturing the global state change in other application. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this package can help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js. Just emit and subscribe events inside your useEffect (don't forget unsubscribe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook only gets called every time the component re-renders. You need to make sure that your component gets re-rendered when `window.pets` changes. Like @Raman Nikitsenka commented, you can use some sort of event emitter to re-render your component when `window.pets` changes.

These are the key things you have to do:

- Create a common event emitter
- `useEffect` to subscribe and unsubscribe to events using `.on()` and `.off()`.
- Somehow re-render the component when external state changes. I use `setState()` with `Symbol()`s.

This is a link to the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-global-state-ctp6d

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had little different use-case where bundles were loaded on different pages. A variation of this worked for me!